# for loop nested with switch skips iterations

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement, iteration, skip

I am building a program to store temperatures of 10 different cities(for eg. city 1...city 10) on two different days day 1 & day 2, in a 2d array.
But my program takes in the first input correctly and then doesn't reads the switch statements first condition and skips it every time it reiterates.

I have created 3 classes Main, temp and search.
temp is used for storing the values in the 2d array and search is used for getting the name of the city and the day corresponding to a) Highest temperature b) lowest temperature.

```
package battlefield;

public class Main 
{
 public static void main(String []args)
 {
     temp t=new temp();
     t.takein();
     search s =new search();
     s.sch();
 }
}

package battlefield;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class temp 
{
 int a[][]=new int[2][10];
 String ch;
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 public temp()
 {
 System.out.println("Default temperature have been set to 15 degree  Celsius. ");
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=15;
        }
    }
  }
  public void takein()
  {

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Do you want to enter more?");
            ch=sc.nextLine();
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Value of i="+i+" Value of j="+j);
            switch(ch)
            {
                case "y": 
                    {System.out.println("Enter temprature on day "+i+" city "+j);
                    a[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
                    break;}
                case " n":
                    continue;
                case " e":
                     break;
            }
            if (ch.equals("e"))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ch.equals("e"))
        {
            break;
        }
    }


  }

  }

   package battlefield;

   public class search extends temp
 {
  String rep;
  int t=0;
   public void sch()
 {
    System.out.println("Do you want to search by highest temperature or lowest?");
    rep=sc.nextLine();
    switch(rep)
    {
          case "h":{for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                {
                    if(t<a[i][j])
                    {
                        t=a[i][j];
                    }
                    else
                        continue;
                }
            }
          for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                {
                    if(t==a[i][j])
                    {
                        System.out.println("City "+j+" has the highest temprature of all on day "+i);
                    }
                    else
                        continue;
                }
            }

          break;}
          case "l":{for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                {
                    if(t>a[i][j])
                    {
                        t=a[i][j];
                    }
                    else
                        continue;
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
             {
                for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                {
                    if(t==a[i][j])
                    {
                        System.out.println("City "+j+" has the lowest temperature of all on day "+i);
                    }
                    else
                        continue;
                }
             }
          break;}
          case "n":break;
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is `nextInt()` that leaves a trailing newline. Change

```
ch=sc.nextLine();
sc.nextLine();
```

to

```
ch=sc.nextLine();
// sc.nextLine();
```

And move that `sc.nextLine()` to

```
case "y": 
{
    System.out.println("Enter temprature on day "+i+" city "+j);
    a[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine(); // <-- here.
    break;
}
```